# Updating AssemblyVersion in pre-build task causes test failure

Tags: c#, msbuild

We have a simple task that, before compiling, makes all of our AssemblyInfo.cs files editable, then updates

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]

to

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.`<SourceGetVersion>`")]

All of our assemblies are signed using the same key.

This kind of thing is probably fairly standard, and it works just fine, except that it causes test failures.

The failures look like this:

> Test method
>   Namespace.Tests.MessageTest.TestMethod
>   threw exception: 
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessComponent.Documents,
>   Version=1.0.0.4344, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

So, I turned on the logging that was suggested, and get this:

> W, 3964, 90, 2010/12/07, 09:57:43.059,
>   TFSBUILD\QTAgent32.exe,  Getting
>   custom attributes for type
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
>   threw exception (will ignore and use
>   the reflection way): 
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessEntity,
>   Version=1.0.0.4344,  Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or
>   one of its dependencies.  The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name:
>   'Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessEntity,
>   Version=1.0.0.4344, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule
>   pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor,
>   Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32*
>   pcNamedArgs)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule
>   module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor,
>   IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32&
>   namedArgs)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32
>   decoratedMetadataToken, Int32
>   pcaCount,     RuntimeType
>   attributeFilterType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean
>   isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) 
>   at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean
>   inherit)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean
>   inherit)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.ReflectHelper.GetAttributes(MemberInfo
>   info, Boolean bInherit)
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = domain\tfsbuildAccount
>   LOG: DisplayName =
>   Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessEntity,
>   Version=1.0.0.4344, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/Builds/4/10/TestResults/tfsbuildAccount-TFSBUILD
>   2010-12-07 09_56_54_x86_Debug/Out LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling
>   assembly :
>   Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessComponent.Edi.Tests,
>   Version=1.0.0.4344, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file:
>   D:\Builds\4\10\TestResults\tfsbuildAccount-TFSBUILD
>   2010-12-07
>   09_56_54_x86_Debug\Out\Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessComponent.Edi.Tests.DLL.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: 
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file
>   from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference:
>   Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessEntity,
>   Version=1.0.0.4344, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/Builds/4/10/TestResults/tfsbuildAccount-TFSBUILD
>   2010-12-07
>   09_56_54_x86_Debug/Out/Namespace.BusinessLayer.BusinessEntity.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name
>   resulted in the mismatch: **Revision
>   Number** ERR: Failed to complete setup
>   of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing
>   terminated.

Now, I may have mixed up the assemblies posting this, but it's the same pattern for all the tests. Mind you, the public keys are all the same, and I can see that all of the revision numbers are the same.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the reference assebly to be not version specific. "Secific Version = False" in the properties tab for the assembly.

Comment: These are project references - that option is disabled.